# UPDATE строк БД MariaDB через PhpMyAdmin на хостинге

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb, hosting

Пытаюсь сделать UPDATE строк БД MariaDB через PhpMyAdmin, где определенное поле (FK) <> 1. Перепробовал все следующие варианты:

```
UPDATE friend SET `CityDistrict_id`=NULL,`Street_id`=NULL,`House_id`=NULL,`Apartment`=NULL WHERE City_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT `City_id` FROM `friend` WHERE City_id!=1)


UPDATE friend SET `CityDistrict_id`=NULL,`Street_id`=NULL,`House_id`=NULL,`Apartment`=NULL WHERE City_id!=1


UPDATE friend SET `CityDistrict_id`=NULL,`Street_id`=NULL,`House_id`=NULL,`Apartment`=NULL WHERE City_id<>1
```

Везде пишет затронуто 0 записей и результата от апдейта нет.

При этом когда я выгружаю:

```
SELECT `City_id` FROM `friend` WHERE City_id!=1
```

мне выдает 1519 строк.

Comment: так поди и ошибку какую-нибудь еще пишет, что, возможно, одно из значений, в которые вы пихаете нулл, не может быть пустым, например?

Comment: @teran, нет, не пишет, все поля, которые я обнуляю по умолчанию в БД NULL

Comment: @Akina, это опечатка в вопросе

Comment: Тогда выполните любой из 2 последних запросов через CLI, а не через это [censored], и посмотрите, что выведется.

Comment: @Akina, что значит через CLI?

Comment: Command-line interface. Штатный клиент командной строки mysql.exe